# How do I get the user (IPrincipal) from a partial view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On a *System.Web.UI.Page.ViewPage* I have access to the current User (*System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal*) but I don't have access to the User through a *System.Web.UI.UserControl.ViewUserControl* (the *ViewPage* property is internal).

How can my partial view (*.ascx*) display information depending on who the *IPrincipal* is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.User
```

Answer (score 4):

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```

Comment: Ok -- this is old, but I stumbled on it anyway ;0

If you do this, you will break unit testing -- use ViewContext.HttpContext.* which uses HttpContextBase and was designed for unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can get to it via the ViewContext

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.User
```